# How to remember checked items after research using submit ajax button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, drupal

For example, if I check the item "Generalist":

[image]

And then I click in the search form, write "Generalist", and click apply (submit), then, using AJAX, the table will filter all results to those containing the word "Generalist":

[image]

Now it displays the result. However, the Item "Generalist" had been checked (it is checked in picture 1), but the "apply" button has unchecked all Items. In every new search the table gets reset.

[image]

How can I keep Items checked during each search?

Comment: This depends entirely on the code you haven't shown us which does the table filtering.

Comment: it is in a CMS, if you want i give you the ajax.js of the view module, but i want a other solution